# {if} conditional prevent running module function

Tags: add-on-development, conditionals, module

I created a module for GitHub's API and am having trouble preventing the module's function `{exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive}` from running given a conditional. The reason this is imperative is that the function actually sends a file to the browser (sets headers, echos, and dies).

```
{if logged_out}{redirect="member/login"}{/if}

{exp:channel:entries require_entry="yes" parse="inward"}
    {addon_github}
        {exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive 
            owner="{owner}" 
            repo="{repo}" 
            ref="{ref}"}
    {/addon_github}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I've tried a few things like putting `{if logged_out}limit="0"{/if}` in the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag.

Another solution I thought of was to pass into my `{exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive}` a parameter like `is_authenticated="{logged_in}"` but for some reason that wouldn't parse the value of {logged_in}.

I don't really want to hardcode checking for logged_in in the module itself. Can you guys/gals think of any other workaround or something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Template Parsing Order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html), you'll see that the redirect, stage 20, is parsed after the modules, stage 15. So, let's try to prevent the parsing of `exp:channel:entries`.

I thought you could try this:

```
{if logged_out}{redirect="member/login"}{/if}

{if logged_in}
{exp:channel:entries require_entry="yes" parse="inward"}
    {addon_github}
        {exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive 
            owner="{owner}" 
            repo="{repo}" 
            ref="{ref}"}
    {/addon_github}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

But, your tests proved that `{if logged_in}` and `{if logged_out}` are advanced conditionals. I didn't realize this until to read your comment. This makes a lot sense, since their parsing need to be done after the page caching, to avoid `logged_out` users to see a `logged_in` cached page.

There's a way to use global variables, that make all conditionals to be advanced, on early parsing stages: using [switchee](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee/tree/develop)!

Please, try this:

```
{exp:switchee variable = "global:logged_in_member_id" parse="inward"}
    {case value="0"}
        {redirect="member/login"}   
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
        {exp:channel:entries require_entry="yes" parse="inward"}
            {addon_github}
                {exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive 
                owner="{owner}" 
                repo="{repo}" 
                ref="{ref}"}
            {/addon_github}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

The prefix `global:` allow us to access the global variables that, otherwise, aren't available until the later stages of parsing.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work but I actually don't think that parse order is the issue. Instead I think EE parses everything and then decides what to do with the output of each tag later. I can sort of prove this by making the module tag output a string instead of literally "echoing" the file directly which I have to do to get this module to work.

Comment: Your test just told us that "if logged_in" and "if logged_out" are advanced conditionals.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah you are right about the advanced conditional, I tried a ``{if TRUE} / {if FALSE}`` and that worked as expected. Let me give this a try.

Comment: Using switchee didn't fix the problem as it still parses the module tag. The solution is to use something like mo_variables it seems. Thanks for pointing me on the correct path, my solution is below :)

Comment: Please, do one more test. Try, instead of `default="yes"`, `#^d+$#`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works with the [mo_variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) extension which early parses for use in simple conditionals (I should extend [mo_variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to support a `{logged_in/out}` var as well):

```
{if "{logged_in_member_id}" == FALSE}{redirect="member/login"}{/if}

{exp:channel:entries require_entry="yes"}
    {addon_github}
        {exp:cl_github:repo_contents_archive 
        owner="{owner}" 
        repo="{repo}" 
        ref="{ref}"
        }
    {/addon_github}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```